# I want to find duplicate characters between n string .How can I change my code?

Tags: java

I want to give n string and find duplicate characters between them an print them.
How can I change my code?
for example for 3 string:

string 1:ABCDEF

string 2:BCDEF

string 3:CDFGH

output:CDF

```
       public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        String str1 ;
        str1=scanner.nextLine();
        String str2;
        str2=scanner.nextLine();
        String str11 = "";
        String str12 = "";
        char[] ch1 = str1.toCharArray();
        char[] ch2 = str2.toCharArray();
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ch1.length; i++) {
            if (!str11.contains(ch1[i] + "")) {
                str11 += ch1[i];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < ch2.length; i++) {
            if (!str12.contains(ch2[i] + "")) {
                str12 += ch2[i];
            }
        }
        char[] ch11 = str11.toCharArray();
        char[] ch12 = str12.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < ch11.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ch12.length; j++) {
                if (ch11[i] == ch12[j]) {
                    System.out.print(ch12[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can start with a two-dimensional `char` array.  The first dimension would be the number of input strings, and the second dimension would be the number of characters in each string.  Use a nested for loop to iterate over the two-dimensional `char` array.

Comment: Your example has 3 input but the code only contains 2 input. Please give more information about how you enter the integer values.

Comment: I want to change my code to n input @Theblank

Comment: This problem for two strings is called finding the "Longest Common Subsequence". It's usually solved by Dynamic Programming. Check out the various solutions on [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-common-subsequence/). Are you sure you are asked to generalize it to 'n' strings?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```html
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter total number of String");
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        findDuplicated(scanner.nextInt());
    }

    public static void findDuplicated(int n){
        if(n<2){
            System.out.println("Number of String should be greater than 1");
            return;
        }
        System.out.print("string 1:");
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        char[] str1 = scanner.nextLine().toCharArray();
        String result="";
        for (int i=1;i<n;i++){
            System.out.print("string "+(i+1)+":");
            char[] str2 = scanner.nextLine().toCharArray();
            result = "";
            for(char chr1:str1){
                for(char chr2:str2){
                    if(chr1 == chr2){
                        result += chr1;
                    }
                }
            }
            str1 = result.toCharArray();
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```